# Highly challenging queryset filtering, sorting and annotation (in Django-based app)

Tags: python, django, performance, django-views, django-queryset

I have a Django-based web-app where users congregate and chat with one another. I've just finished writing a feature whereby users can make their own "chat groups", centered around any topic of interest. These could either be *private*, or *publically* visible.

My next challenge is showing a list of **all existing public groups**, paginated, and sorted by *the most happening group first*. After some deep thinking, I've decided that the most happening group is one which sees the most unique visitors (silent or otherwise) in the previous **60 mins**. To be sure, by unique I mean distinct users, and not the same user hitting a group again and again.

What's the *most efficient* way to get the desired, ordered query-set in the `get_queryset()` method of my class-based view associated to this popularity listing? Secondly, what's the *most efficient* way to also annotate **total distinct views** to each group object in the same queryset, so that I can additionally *show* total views, while sort according to what's currently hot?

---

Relevant models are:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    topic = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(200)], null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    private = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class GroupTraffic(models.Model):
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    which_group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The relevant view is:

```
class GroupListView(ListView):
    model = Group
    form_class = GroupListForm
    template_name = "group_list.html"
    paginate_by = 25

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Group.objects.filter(private=0,date__gte=???).distinct('grouptraffic__visitor').annotate(recent_views=Count('grouptraffic__???')).order_by('-recent_views').annotate(total_views=Count('grouptraffic__which_group=group'))
```

As you can see, I've struggled rather mightily in the `get_queryset(self)` method above, annotating twice and what not. Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot combine `annotate()` and `distinct()` in a single django query. So you can try like:

```
date = datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

Next query is to get the grouptraffic with unique visitors

```
new_traff = GroupTraffic.objects.filter(time__gte=date).distinct('visitor','which_group').values_list('id',flat=True)

trendingGrp_ids = GroupTraffic.objects.filter(id__in=new_traff).values('which_group').annotate(total=Count('which_group')).order_by('-total')
```

The above query will get you trending groupids ordered by `total` like:

```
[{'total': 4, 'which_group': 2}, {'total': 2, 'which_group': 1}, {'total': 1, 'which_group': 3}]
```

Here `total` refers to no. of new unique visitors for each group in the last 60 minutes.

Now iterate over trendingGrp_ids to get the trending trendingGrps with views:

```
trendingGrps = [Group.objects.filter(id=grp['which_group']).extra(select={"views":grp['total']})[0] for grp in trendingGrp_ids]
```

Update:

To get **all** public groups, and sort them by how hot they are via measuring the traffic they received in the past 1 hr.

```
new_traff = GroupTraffic.objects.filter(time__gte=date,which_group__private=0).distinct('visitor','which_group').values_list('id',flat=True)

trendingGrp_ids = GroupTraffic.objects.filter(id__in=new_traff).values('which_group').annotate(total=Count('which_group')).order_by('-total')

trendingGrps = [Group.objects.filter(id=grp['which_group']).extra(select={"views":grp['total']})[0] for grp in trendingGrp_ids]

trndids = [grp['which_group'] for grp in trendingGrp_ids]

nonTrendingGrps = Group.objects.filter(private=0).exclude(id__in=trndids).extra(select={"views":0})

allGrps = trendingGrps.append(nonTrendingGrps)
```

Comment: So far, so good, thus accepting it. Will open a new question if something goes south in the future. Thanks!

Comment: So one thing it lacked was, it didn't show ALL public groups, it only showed the ones that trended in the last 60 mins. I actually needed *all public groups*, sorted by how they trended in the past 60 mins.

Comment: @HassanBaig how are you differentiating b/w public and private groups? What does private field contain for public and private Groups?

Comment: anush, simply group.private=='0' selects all public groups. Also, I tried a different query on proceedings, one posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727523/crafting-a-query-to-construct-a-challenging-django-queryset

Comment: any word on how to change this sol to target *all* public groups, rather than just the trending ones?

Comment: @HassanBaig can you try: `new_traff = GroupTraffic.objects.filter(time__gte=date,which_group__private=0).distinct('visitor','which_group').values_list('id',flat=True)`

Comment: Ah, no mate :-( See, I want to get *all* public groups, and sort them by how hot they are via measuring the traffic they received in the past 1 hr. With your way, I'm not going to get all groups, I'll leave those out that didn't see any activity in the past 1 hour. They ought to have showed up, just sorted last.

Comment: When I think deeply about it, I realize that all one needs to do is concatenate, to trendingGrps, the set of non-trendingGrps, and then sort the result. Something like `non_trending = Group.objects.exclude(id__in=trendingGroup_ids)` and `all_groups = non_trending | trendingGrps` Sadly, this gives me a strange error: **subquery has too many columns**

Comment: Actually *new_traff* ends up containing GroupTraffic objects. Thus when we do `nonTrendingGrps = Group.objects.filter(private=0).exclude(id__in=new_traff)`, we end up trying to exclude Group objects via looking within GroupTraffic IDs (incorrect comparison). As a result, nonTrendingGrps show incorrect results.

Comment: @HassanBaig oh i missed that...i have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

1)Create a separate function that tallies the distinct views in a chatbox. For every chatbox, put the result in a list. Return the biggest value in the list and assign it to a variable. Import the function and filter with the variable.

2) Make a set for each box. The set contains all the distinct users of the chatbox. Filter by the lenght of the set.