# Crafting a query to construct a challenging Django queryset

Tags: python, sql, django, performance, postgresql

I have a Django website where users can make groups and other users then visit the groups to post content. Groups can be open to public, or kept private. The models are simply:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    topic = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(200)])
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    private = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class GroupTraffic(models.Model):
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    which_group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

Can you help me frame a listing of all groups on the website, satisfying the following rules?

1) I want to display **only and all public groups** (i.e. `group.private='0'`)

2) To each group, I want to annotate the **total views it has ever had**

3) Finally, groups listing should be sorted by **number of unique visitors in the past 1 hour**

To achieve the above, this is what I have tried (please scroll):

```
date = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=1)
groups = Group.objects.filter(private='0').annotate(total_views=Count('grouptraffic__visitor')).extra(select={'uniques':'SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT visitor) FROM links_grouptraffic AS grptraffic WHERE (links_grouptraffic.time > %s AND links_grouptraffic.which_group_id=grptraffic.which_group_id)'},select_params=(date,),).order_by('-uniques')
```

Note that `links` is the name of the app. To satisfy (1) I use filter, to satisfy (2) I annotate a Count aggregation, and to satisfy (3) I use extra with some SQL inside it. It doesn't work; I get the error: **column "visitor" does not exist**. *But column visitor DOES exist* - see models - hence I'm unsure what this error means. Here's a screenshot; it has some more information: 
[image]

Can you help me frame queries that satisfy 1, 2 and 3? My DB is postgres, and efficient performance is key for me.

---

*Note: I also [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33580734/4936905), it was interesting but the solution didn't satisfy (1), nor could I modify it to do so.*

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the name of your vistor field in the postgres table will be "visitor_id" as it is a ForeignKey. It is stored as an integer in the database.

Comment: You mean to say, the correct query is: `SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT visitor_id) FROM links_grouptraffic AS grptraffic WHERE (links_grouptraffic.time > %s AND links_grouptraffic.which_group_id=grptraffic.which_group_id`?

Comment: Not the same. This time it gives me: **syntax error at or near "SELECT"** (not much to go on)